# Powershell Xml query

Tags: xml, powershell

Here is exam XML..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
    <book>
        <title>a book</title>
        <writer>Tom</writer>
    </book> 
    <book>
        <title>b book</title>
        <writer>John</writer>
    </book> 
    <book>
        <title>c book</title>
        <writer>Tom</writer>
    </book> 
</books>
```

I want to find a list of this writer is Tom.
So my script is

```
[xml]$books = Get-Content C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\books.xml
$books.book| %{$_.book.writer -match 'Tom'}
```

But this script show only writer...

```
writer
Tom
Tom
```

I want to see like this

```
title      writer
a book     Tom
c book     Tom
```

help me plz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `?` , a.k.a. `Where-Object` instead of `%`:

```
$books.book| ?{$_.book.writer -match 'Tom'}
```

This is a filter on the previous pipeline element, restricting what comes out of it, while with `ForEach-Object` you're projecting, i.e. creating a new sequence of objects.

Your code and output don't make sense, though. First of all, `$books` shouldn't have a `book` property but instead `books`. You should have seen

```
True
False
True
```

instead of `writer` objects, unless there are multiple `writer` elements per book.

Answer (score 1):

I meant to write

```
select-xml -Path C:\XML\doc2.txt -XPath "//book[writer='Tom']//ancestor::book"
```

> title  writer
>
> a book Tom c book Tom

Ernest Brant

Answer (score 0):

With Powershell 4 just use

$books.books.book